# Setting up an htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

I'm in the process of rebuilding a site and want to set it up as follows:

1 ) Pages other than index.html e.g. www.website.co.uk/support/web-design.html becomes www.website.co.uk/support/web-design/

2) Pages that aren't in subfolders e.g. www.website.co.uk/contact.html becomes www.website.co.uk/contact/

I know I should use a .htaccess file. I've looked various sites explaining htaccess and mod_rewrite but need help. Can anyone explain how this should this be setup to achieve the above?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+([^\?]+)\.html
RewriteCond %1 !^index$
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.html [L]
```

These rules would go in the htaccess file in your document root

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L,NC]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.html [L]
```